# Adding an order comments block to onepage checkout

Tags: magento-1.7, onepage-checkout, custom-options

I am trying to add customer comments to the onepage checkout review tab. I would like to eventually post the results in the sales order email that is sent back on checkout. Based on research I think that I need to build an observer to tie to the event checkout_type_onepage_save_order. Any help with this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The frontend events that you'd be looking at would be:

- `checkout_type_onepage_save_order`, and
- `checkout_type_multishipping_create_orders_single` depending on if you allow this

There is an extension by Magemaven which does exactly what you're looking for, see it on [MagentoConnect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magemaven-ordercomment.html).

This tool will allow you to download the source code directly prior to installation.

[Download Magento Extension](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php)

Let me know if you need any further explanation.